# How to resize a window when the bottom right is not visible?

Tags: window-buttons

I am trying to change the default pdf viewer on my Kile Latex frontend. When I reach **Settings** ▸ **Configure - Kile** ▸ **Tools** ▸ **Build** ▸ **ViewPDF** I am able to make the appropriate change.

Unfortunately, in the pop-up window for **Configure - Kile**, I am not able to see the bottom right corner. A right angle with an arrow does appear near the top left corner. But I am not able to resize the window using it. Consequently I am not able to save the changes, rendering the entire operation pointless.

The only option available on the top bar of the pop-up window is to close it. There's no minimize or restore option available.

EDIT: I am using Ubuntu 11.10, with Virtual Box (Full screen mode) along with gnome (version 3.2.1). I dislike Unity. But I guess my current predicament is because I have gotten rid of Unity.

EDIT (Images explaining the issue):
Screenshot when I open **Configure - Kile**:
[image: Screenshot when I open Configure - Kile]

Screenshot when I reach the ViewPDF option:

[image: Screenshot when I reach the ViewPDF option]

Comment: I have Guest Additions. I think I am using VB at its full potential. I think the problem lies some where else. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: `Alt`+`F8` does not work either?

Comment: Nopes alt-space doesn't work either.
Tried alt-f8 too.
The issue seems to be that the options are too many in number. It causes the size to exceed the screen limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the problem of clicking `OK` & `Cancel` buttons hidden at the bottom of an over-sized windows is `Alt` + `F7`. After pressing that, using the arrows keys, windows which are not maximized, can be moved (at least partially) beyond the upper bound of the desktop screen. Obviously, when moved sufficiently upwards, a non-maximized sub-window, will present its lower-most buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag with **mouse wheel(mouse middle button)**

## EDIT

need to edit `$HOME/.kde/share/config/kilerc` file

```
[Tool/ViewPDF/Okular] 
class=View 
command=FoxitReader 
from=pdf 
menu=View 
options='%target' 
state=Viewer 
to=pdf 
type=Process
```

And change needed settings

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, but it doesn't help. I mean it works but I am still not able to get the window size small enough to see the `OK` and `Cancel` buttons. :(

Comment: @ShashankSawant can you go to chat room?

Comment: Sorry I omitted a fact. I don't think it should matter but I am including it in the original question. I am using Virtual Box.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution I used in this case; I changed the taskbar location to right (or any other than bottom) temporarily. Right click on taskbar and  then click properties. You'll find the choice to move taskbar there.

Cheers
A.R.K